# Docker / Django - Migrate inside a container

Tags: django, database, docker, migration

everyone.

I have Django in Docker and it seems to work pretty normal.
But I have added a field in my model.
I tried this order:

```
docker-compose up -d

docker exec -it ff71e5e414a4 python manage.py makemigrations user

No changes detected in app 'user'
```

But they are

```
docker exec -it ff71e5e414a4 python manage.py migrate
```

No migrations to apply

Tried to do this way:

```
Starting billing-api-master_db_1 ... done
Migrations for 'user':
  user/migrations/0005_auditentry.py
    - Create model AuditEntry

chainsa@chainsaw MINGW64 /f/Django_work/billing-api-master/billing-api-master/ap
p
$ docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate
Starting billing-api-master_db_1 ... done
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, iptv, ser
vice, sessions, sites, socialaccount, user
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won
't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage
.py migrate' to apply them.
```

It says that model is created, but it is existing already.

My expected response is to add a new field of existing model to DB

Sorry for a nooby question

Thank you

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'


services:
  web:
    environment:
        - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
    build:
      context: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
        - ./app:f/Django_work/billing-api-master/billing-api-master/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django_dev
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: How are you mounting your code into the container? Can you share the section of your `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Added................

Comment: You're not mounting your local code properly, a colon (`:`) is needed to specify and separate the local directory and mount location. Your volume should look like this: `- .:/app`

Comment: ty for answer. it's returned: manage.py not found. i've changed local to ./app and result is the same. ./app:./app - mount path must be absolute (tried, didn't work)

Comment: It looks like you've attached a couple of image files to the question in place of the contents of your `docker-compose.yml` file and your reproduction instructions.  Can you replace these with the plain-text contents of these files?